# xslt to transform the xml nodes dynamically

Tags: xml, xslt

**i  am working to get the nodes of my xml changed dynamically based on the key value, below is my original xml, following that is the xml i wanted to be after the xsl conversion.**

original xml:

```
<Refd>
  <randr>

  <KeyPair>
  <Key>CM_001</Key>
  <Value>sometext</Value>
  </KeyPair>

  <KeyPair>
  <Key>CM_002</Key>
  <Value>sometext/Value>
  </KeyPair>

  <KeyPair>
  <Key>CM_003</Key>
  <Value>sometext/Value>
  </KeyPair>

  </randr>
  </Refd>
```

***trying to get this as below:***

```
  <Refd>
  <randr>

  <KeyPair_001>
  <Key>CM_001</Key>
  <Value>sometext</Value>
  </KeyPair_001>

  <KeyPair_002>
  <Key>CM_002</Key>
  <Value>sometext/Value>
  </KeyPair_002>

  <KeyPair_003>
  <Key>CM_003</Key>
  <Value>sometext/Value>
  </KeyPair_003>

  </randr>
  </Refd>
```

**trying to get the xslt working by the below , but it only gets me for just 1 tag and the others remain unchanged, can i get it to work for multiple tags. Thank you in advance**

```
  <xsl:template match="Refd/randr/KeyPair">
    <xsl:variable name="ename">
      <xsl:text>Key</xsl:text>
      <xsl:if test="Key ='CM_001'">
        <xsl:text>001</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{$ename}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="KeyPair">
    <xsl:element name="KeyPair{substring-after(Key, 'CM')}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that numbering element names is considered bad practice. If your target application demands it, then it's unavoidable; but in general it is best to use an attribute for this purpose.